# scrollViewWillBeginDragging: Not getting called in UICollectionview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have an `UIView` in which an `UICollectionview` is there. For knowing the scroll distance of `UICollectionview` I used `scrollViewWillBeginDragging:` , but it is not getting called.
Sample Code is

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGPoint translation = [scrollView.panGestureRecognizer translationInView:scrollView.superview];

    if(translation.y > 0)
    {
        //dragging down
        _reusableview.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    } 
    else
    {
        // dragging up
        _reusableview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: you havent added scrollView!???

Comment: is collectionview's delegate properly set?

Comment: @sriramhegde: UICollectionView is a subclass of UIScrollView.

Comment: do i need to add scroll view too???

Comment: @rokjarc yes we have done that..

Comment: just checking so this probably is your hierarchy? viewcontroller -> view -> view with collection view. So which one is the delegate?

Comment: what about scrollViewDidScroll: - is this one called?

Comment: what is  _reusableview? Could you explain me?

Comment: I tried your posted coding.It works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you have added the UIscrollViewDelegate and set the UIcollectionView delegate to the class.
Then scrollViewWillBeginDragging() function will be called when collectionView is scrolled.

Inside the function you can confirm if the scrollView isKindOfClass UICollectionView.

Answer (score 1):

UICollectionView is a sub class of UIScrollView. Anyone can detect the delegate methods of scroll view by keeping in mind some points.

1. Set the class as delegate of scroll view
   You can do this in .h file and .m file

In .h file

```
@interface DemoViewController : UIViewController<UIScrollViewDelegate>
{

}
```

In .m file

```
@interface SplashViewController ()<UIScrollViewDelegate>
{

}
```

2. Make the datasource and delegate of collection view that class.
Example:

```
collectionView.delegate = self;
collectionView.dataSource = self;
```

Try out above steps.
Hope it will work for you.